# U.S.S. Defiant's phasers change color

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Throughout the course of DS9, I've noticed that the Defiant either fires yellow phasers or orange-yellow phasers. This is the [yellow phasers](https://youtu.be/CUQ2nmKNH3Y?t=108) and this is an example of the [yellow-orange phasers](https://youtu.be/eo_X5SphRbE?t=13) I mentioned. Why are there two different colors and which is the "correct" one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Federation Starships can fire phasers at different frequencies. This was best described during TNG's "Best of Both Worlds" (Part 1) when Data rapidly changes frequencies to dislodge the Enterprise from the Borg tractor beam. You can actively see the color change during each shot.

Therefore it's possible, that in-universe, they were tuned to slightly different frequencies during the various battles.

Comment: Hmm, that's a really nice answer and it makes a lot of sense. It also might explain First Contact's red-orange phasers, maybe that frequency was used to fight the Borg

Comment: @HyperBeta can you accept the answer? thanks.

Comment: Oh thanks for telling me, I did not know you could accept answers as I'm quite new here.

Comment: @HyperBeta There's a Tour you were prompted to take when you joined, which teaches you all about the site.

Comment: That [Tour] is located here if you haven't seen it already.